# leiningen, lein, clojure build behind proxy server with lein_tool_deps plugin

Tags: java, maven, clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

I am new to clojure and I am trying to build a porject on a system that is behind a proxy server.

Every lein command I run tries to fetch middleware dependencies using the `:middleware [lein-tools-deps.plugin/resolve-dependencies-with-deps-edn]` tool.  However, whenever it tries to download depedencies stated within the `deps.edn` file Java throws a connection timeout while trying to connect to `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/`

environment variables

- http_proxy
- https_proxy
- no_proxy

are configured properly.

I configured `/home/<user>/.m2/settings.xml` to use the proxy as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>my-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>myproxy.....</host>
      <port>XXXX</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>...|*.my.domain|localhost|127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

deps.edn is

```
{:deps    {org.clojure/clojure         {:mvn/version "1.10.0"}
           org.clojure/clojurescript   {:mvn/version "1.10.516}
           .... }
 :paths   ["src/cljs" "resources" "target"]
 :aliases {:build {:main-opts ["-m" "figwheel.main" "-b" "dev" "-r"]}}}
```

Any lein command (ex: `lein deps`) results in `Could not transfer artifact org.clojure:clojure:pom:1.10.0 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): connect timed out`

However, removing `:middleware` from the file `project.clj`  allows me to fetch any dependency not in defined in the plugin.

How can I get the plugin to use the http proxy?

Comment: I'm not using this approach/plugin but could it be that your `protocol` configuration is incorrect? (you have `http` in your `settings.xml`) Notice that remote repositories should use _HTTPS_ protocol, e.g. `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/`

Comment: I think typically that is the protocol the proxy server ex: http://myproxy.mydomain.com:8888/